# Start a method through a table row

Tags: ajax, jsf, datatable, row, facelets

I'm french, I will do in my best to speack english with you.
I have a datatable with books and information books. 
I want my table to create a button for adding my book to my order (Order myOrder) but I can not, despite my attempts to do so.

My facelet :

```
    <div class="divListLivres">
            <h1>Liste des livres</h1>

            <h:dataTable styleClass="order-table"
                headerClass="order-table-header"
                rowClasses="order-table-odd-row,order-table-even-row" var="_book"
                value="#{catalogueIBean.books}">

                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Titre</f:facet>
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{_book.title}" />

                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Editeur</f:facet>
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{_book.editor}" />

                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Auteur</f:facet>
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{_book.author.firstName}" />
                    <h:outputLabel value=" #{_book.author.lastName}" />

                </h:column>

                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Prix unitaire</f:facet>
                    <h:outputLabel value=" #{_book.unitPrice}" />
                    <h:outputLabel value="€" />
                </h:column>

            </h:dataTable>
        </div>
```

Can you help me? Either by redirecting the action to a method of my bean (CatalogueIBean whith method "addOrder(){}") making sure to add the line directly in my object "Order myOrder." Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

you can easily add another column of a command button to your datatable in that way you will also have a button in each row which can redirect you to your required method

```
 <p:column style="width:6%" headerText="Add to Order">
 <p:commandButton id="addOrderButton"     
  action="#{catalogueIBean.addOrder}" immediate="true" ajax="true"
  icon="ui-icon-folder-open">
    <f:param name="id" value="#{_book.id}" />               
    </p:commandButton>
    </p:column>
```

note: you can change the icon as you want or remove if you dont want an icon instead you can name the button by the value attribute of the button. Also if you dont want your button to be in your data table you can make a new form outside the form of data table and add your button there.

your backing bean should be

```
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Map requestMap = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    String value = (String) requestMap.get("id");
    Integer id = Integer.parseInt(value);
```

now that you have the id of each row you can traverse to your required object

Comment: if you want to retrieve the order of the line you are selecting in data table then i have updated the code. what you need to do is provide an id to each row in data table, send the id by using <f:param name="id" value="#{_book.id}" /> and recieve it in the method of your backing bean

Answer (score 0):

The fonctione "AddOrder" does not start but my method "init ()" yes.

I want to retrieve the "order" object of my line, I do not see how that is possible here.

It should incorporate something for the ajax work?

Here is the beginning of my bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "catalogueIBean")
@RequestScoped
public class CatalogueIBean {

    @Inject
    private FacesContext facesContext;

    @Inject
    private BookService bookService;

    // ////////////////Variables de facelet//////////////////

    private String title;
    private String isbn13;
    private Double price;
    private int selectAuthor;
    private List<Author> authors;
    private String selectEditor;
    private List<SelectItem> editorNames;
    private List<Book> books;
    private Book selectedBook;

    // ////////////////Méthodes de facelet//////////////////

    public String addOrder(/*parameter ??*/) throws Exception {
        //add order of the line of datatable in my order (or create an orderLine)
        return null;
    }

// ////////////////Initialisation//////////////////

@PostConstruct
public void init() throws Exception {
    .......
}
```

thank you